# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9 - Cannot Find or Install RPM Python Bindings?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, python, rpm

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9, and I cannot find the RPM Python bindings?

I am trying to install rpm-py-installer-0.7.0 and it throws an error:

```
RPM Python binding on system Python should be installed manually.
Install the proper RPM package of python{,2,3}-rpm.
```

So, I searched the Internet, and found RPM Python bindings, but nothing for RHEL 6...
I tried using pip and yum to install python2-rpm, but it found nothing (the package does not exist).

I need to be able to install python2-rpm so that I can get rpm-py-installer installed.

---

Here is the code that is failing:

```
if self.python.is_system_python():
            if self.python.is_python_binding_installed():
                message = '''
RPM Python binding already installed on system Python.
Nothing to do.
'''
                Log.info(message)
                raise InstallSkipError(message)
            else:
                message = '''
RPM Python binding on system Python should be installed manually.
Install the proper RPM package of python{,2,3}-rpm.
'''
                raise InstallError(message)
```

Basically...

```
self.python.is_python_binding_installed()
```

... is returning false.

Comment: Have you tried `yum install rpm-python` ?  That's in the CentOS6.9 base so I assume it's available on RedHat.  It includes the `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/rpm` directory.

Comment: I ran `yum install rpm-python` and it said it was already installed...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can install the package with following command.

```
yum localinstall rpm-py-installer-0.7.0
```

In normally, as you know, yum util is getting packages from repositories throughthe network.
But in this case, you have already downloaded rpm-py-installer-0.7.0 from internet to your server, so, designate localinstall command to install from local directory.
However, dependency related errors may occur.

Comment: When I run that yum command, I get: `Skipping: rpm-py-installer-0.7.0, filename does not end in .rpm.` Also, with rpm-py-installer, I managed to compile the tarball, but when I went to install it, it gave the same error about the missing RPM Python bindings.

Comment: I inspected the code again and found that the install.py script is looking for the 'rpm-python' or 'rpm' package names in pip. And, it is not there, so it errors out...

Answer (score 0):

I could not find 'rpm-python' package for pip anywhere, but I found a wheel for just 'rpm'.
Here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/rpm/#description

Just install that, then re-install 'rpm-py-installer' and it should have no more errors!

Thanks.
Erik W.